# How to display Multiple markers in MapView With pincolor

Tags: javascript, react-native, latitude-longitude, mapview

I want to display on my map multiple markers for multiple latitude and longitude in MapView on React Native.
I am getting the latitude and longitude by fetch Data from API.
Now How Can I show In my React Native for All position in map using those Data.

my codes is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    devices?.map(async (id) => {

        await fetch(`https://www.schools.com/sc/api/${id}`, requestOptions)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(function (response) {
             return setDataLoc([parseFloat(response.data?.latitude), parseFloat(response.data?.longitude)])
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    })

}, [])


const [curLoc, setCurLoc] = useState({
    latitude: 5.055252,
    longitude: 115.9456243,
    latitudeDelta: 0.004757,
    longitudeDelta: 0.006866,

})

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
            initialRegion={curLoc}>
            {devices?.map((val) => {
                return (<Marker
                    coordinate={val.dataLoc}
                    pinColor="black">
                </Marker>)
            })}
        </MapView>
    </View>
);
```

Now i have more latitude and longitude to display.
I get my data after fetch something's like,

Output:

```
[5.7689,110.5677]
[5.2345,111.5623]
[5.6652,112.7890]
```

After execute this I can't able to view any marker on my Map.

So I want to display those 3 latitude and longitude location in my Map View.

how can I do all position using marker I can display in Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you error comes from the wrong type you are giving in props to coordinate on the marker component, coordinate should be like that: `{ latitude : number , longitude : number }`

```
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
    
    const [curLoc, setCurLoc] = useState({
      latitude: 5.055252,
      longitude: 115.9456243,
      latitudeDelta: 0.004757,
      longitudeDelta: 0.006866,
    })

    marketToDisplay = [
      {latitude: 5.7689, longitude: 110.5677},
      {latitude: 5.2345, longitude: 111.5623},
      {latitude: 5.6652, longitude: 112.7890},
    ]
  
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView style={styles.map} initialRegion={curLoc}>
            marketToDisplay.map((val, index) => {
              <Marker
                key={index}
                coordinate={val}
              />
            }
            <Marker coordinate={this.state.coordinate} />
          </MapView>
        </View>
      );
    }
```